# Unable to reference CloudFormation resource in serverless.yml. Invalid variable reference syntax for variable UserPoolId

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, yaml, serverless-framework, serverless

I am using the Serverless framework to deploy a serverless app to AWS. However, the CloudFormation part is not working as expected. I have looked up on the web and couldn't find anything wrong with my YAML.

I am creating a `UserPool` and then `UserPoolClient` by using CloudFormation. I have the following YAML for `resources:`

```yaml
    resources:
      Resources:
        HttpBucket:
          Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
          Properties:
            BucketName: ${self:service}-${UserPoolId}
            AccessControl: PublicRead
            WebsiteConfiguration:
              IndexDocument: index.html
        UserPool:
          Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
          Properties:
            UserPoolName: ${self:service}-user-pool
            MfaConfiguration: "OFF"
            EmailVerificationSubject: "Your verification code"
            EmailVerificationMessage: "Your verification code is {####}. "  
            Schema:
              - Name: name
                AttributeDataType: String
                Mutable: true
                Required: true
              - Name: email
                AttributeDataType: String
                Mutable: false
                Required: true
              - Name: teamName
                AttributeDataType: String
                Mutable: true
                Required: false
              - Name: custom:supportedTeam
                AttributeDataType: String
                Mutable: true
                Required: false
              - Name: custom:payment
                AttributeDataType: String
                Mutable: true
                Required: false
                DeveloperOnlyAttribute: true
            UsernameAttributes:
              - email
            AutoVerifiedAttributes:
              - email
            AdminCreateUserConfig:
              InviteMessageTemplate:
                EmailMessage: 'Your username is {username} and temporary password is {####}. '
                EmailSubject: Your temporary password
                SMSMessage: 'Your username is {username} and temporary password is {####}. '
              UnusedAccountValidityDays: 7
              AllowAdminCreateUserOnly: false
            Policies:
              PasswordPolicy:
                RequireLowercase: true
                RequireSymbols: false
                RequireNumbers: true
                MinimumLength: 6
                RequireUppercase: true
        UserPoolClient:
          Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient"
          Properties:
            ClientName: ${self:service}-client
            GenerateSecret: false
            UserPoolId: 
              Ref: UserPool
      Outputs:
        UserPoolId:
          Value: 
            Ref: UserPool
          Export:
            Name: "UserPool::Id"
        UserPoolClientId:
          Value: 
            Ref: UserPoolClient
          Export:
            Name: "UserPoolClient::Id"
```

I am unable to reference `UserPool` when specifying `UserPoolClient` (to be used as `UserPoolId`).

The following:

```
UserPoolId: 
  Ref: UserPool
```

yields the error:

> Invalid variable reference syntax for variable UserPoolId. You can
>   only reference env vars, options, & files. You can check our docs for
>   more info.

Another thing which I am not sure about, I have seen people sharing YAML containing the following syntax:

```
UserPoolId: !Ref UserPool
```

But it also fails and errors about the invalid syntax (due to `!Ref`). Can anyone clear me on this?

Answer (score 4):

After taking some time off the computer, I thought that the problem could be somewhere else which is what the case here.

I was using `${UserPoolId}` under environment variables and realized that this is where the problem lies. I changed to the following way and the problem got solved. I was not referencing user pool ID correctly (it was referencing serverless.yml local variable named UserPoolId which didn't exist)

```
userPoolId: 
      Ref: UserPool
```

This was just my mistake and is now solved.

Answer (score 1):

I found whilst writing my template it sometimes would do incorrect syntax highlighting and I would have to write it so that it couldn't check.

Ref: UserPool

Fn::Sub: '${UserPool}'

By swapping it with Substitute, it cannot check that the contents of the string are valid and then it will construct a string containing the Ref to the UserPool, or the user pool id

[Fn::Sub documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html)

Comment: Can you elaborate? It also errors with the message: `unknown tag !<!Sub>`

Comment: @UsamaEjaz I've updated my answer can you try that instead?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer actually triggered a thought which lead to the solution (was my mistake). 
I see, I can use cloudformation parameters like `Fn::Sub` (much thanks to you).